# How can I replace all keys of a hash in a string with their values?

Tags: perl, hash

I am coding a script with a variable system. The program uses a hash with a value for each keyword, but I don't know how to continue
when it comes to replacing all keywords in a string.

The code of the replacement looks like:

```
while ( ($key, $value) = each %variables_hash ) {
    if ( -1 != index($CMD, $key) ) {
        # Here should be the code that I cant think how to do
    }
}
```

`$CMD` is the input string, and
`%variables_hash` is the hash that contains the variabless

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to be a Perl programmer, then you need to read the Perl FAQ. [This is from perlfaq4.](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-expand-variables-in-text-strings%3F)

> **How can I expand variables in text strings?**
>
> (contributed by brian d foy)
>
> If you can avoid it, don't, or if you can use a templating system,
>   such as Text::Template or Template Toolkit, do that instead. You might 
>   even be able to get the job done with `sprintf` or `printf`:
>
> ```
>   my $string = sprintf 'Say hello to %s and %s', $foo, $bar;
> ```
>
> However, for the one-off simple case where I don't want to pull out a 
>   full templating system, I'll use a string that has two Perl scalar 
>   variables in it. In this example, I want to expand `$foo` and `$bar` to 
>   their variable's values:
>
> ```
>    my $foo = 'Fred';
>    my $bar = 'Barney';
>    $string = 'Say hello to $foo and $bar';
> ```
>
> One way I can do this involves the substitution operator and a double
>   `/e` flag. The first `/e` evaluates `$1` on the replacement side and
>   turns it into `$foo`. The second `/e` starts with `$foo` and replaces
>   it with its value. `$foo`, then, turns into 'Fred', and that's finally 
>   what's left in the string:
>
> ```
>    $string =~ s/(\$\w+)/$1/eeg; # 'Say hello to Fred and Barney'
> ```
>
> The `/e` will also silently ignore violations of strict, replacing 
>   undefined variable names with the empty string. Since I'm using the
>   `/e` flag (twice even!), I have all of the same security problems I
>   have with `eval` in its string form. If there's something odd in
>   `$foo`, perhaps something like `@{[ system "rm -rf /" ]}`, then I could 
>   get myself in trouble.
>
> To get around the security problem, I could also pull the values from a 
>   hash instead of evaluating variable names. Using a single `/e`, I can
>   check the hash to ensure the value exists, and if it doesn't, I can 
>   replace the missing value with a marker, in this case `???` to signal
>   that I missed something:
>
> ```
>    my $string = 'This has $foo and $bar';
>    my %Replacements = (
>        foo  => 'Fred',
>    );
>    # $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/$Replacements{$1}/g;
>    $string =~ s/\$(\w+)/
>        exists $Replacements{$1} ? $Replacements{$1} : '???'
>    /eg;
>
>    print $string;
> ```

Comment: Well, thanks too, is well explained but I find the first method more intuitive, and to be honest, I am not that kind of "regular expresion lover", but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) to replace the substring. I used `while` instead of `if` so you can replace multiple occurrences. [length](http://p3rl.org/length) `$key` is used to determine the length of the substring to replace.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %variables_hash = (
    _number => 123,
    _name   => 'John Smith',
);

my $CMD = 'INSERT INTO customers (name, code) VALUES("_name", _number)';


while (my ($key, $value) = each %variables_hash) {
    while (-1 != ( my $pos = index $CMD, $key )) {
        substr $CMD, $pos, length $key, $value;
    }
}

print $CMD, "\n";
```

Another option would be to use substitution (see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)), or a Template (e.g. [Template](http://p3rl.org/Template)).

### Substitution:

```
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %variables_hash;

$CMD =~ s/($regex)/$variables_hash{$1}/g;
```

Note that if one variable name is a substring of another, you probably want to process them from the longest to the shortest (the same applies to the `substr` solution); so you might need to say

```
map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %variables_hash;
```

### Template:

Note that variables can't start with underscores, but they aren't needed, as the variables are included in template tags, so you won't accidentally replace `name` when it refers to the column name.

```
use Template;

my %variables_hash = (
    number => 123,
    name   => 'John Smith',
);

my $CMD = 'INSERT INTO customers (name, code) VALUES("[% name %]", [% number %])';

my $template = 'Template'->new;
$template->process(\$CMD, \%variables_hash);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found that the first method is more suitable for my chase, and is well explained, thanks again!